# SignalR how to receive 64bit integer with typescript client

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, bigint

Sending 64bit integers from the the .net signalr server is not a problem.
However on the client side, this gets complicated, as number does not cover 64bit integers entirely.
Documentation does not mention anything either. Would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How about convert it to string and pass it?

Comment: As far as I know TS SignalR client does not support custom json converters to deserialize it on the client side from string.